# No matching authentication protocol Informatica DVO

Tags: oracle, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am facing issue while installation the DVO 15.0 Application.
Below Error is coming while connecting

**[Oracle]ORA-28040. No matching authentication protocol**

looks like a driver issue but not sure which one.

any help?

-TIA

Comment: Which driver are you using for it? Your Oracle version?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov: I am using Oracle driver to connect to.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov: Oracle Version is 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ashud1:you can add below parameters in the sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=11
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=11
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=11

Also update the Jar files of 
PC($INFA_HOME/services/shared/jars/thirdparty/*dworacle*.jar) with the dworacle.jar 
file present at dvo installation path DVO/lib
```

Comment: Thanks , this indeed has solved the issue . Many Thanks